# Resting Heart Rate method

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I am having a difficult time getting the resting heart rate from healthkitstore and found this article on this site.

[Query to Healthstore for Resting Heart Rate not returning any values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391037/query-to-healthstore-for-resting-heart-rate-not-returning-any-values)

However, I am not sure how to call the method within my view controller to assign its value to a variable for use to calculate heart rate reserve and heart rate target zones.  This is for a fitness app that I am working on.

Can anyone explain how to call this method?  I am having such a difficult time with this one and am obviously overlooking something.

Thank you so much!

Kevin

Comment: have you asked for permissions for restingHeartRate, it has separate permission

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I have included .restingHeartRate and .heartRate to my permissions and they are granted.