# Swift syntax for calling an escaping closure/function...?

Tags: swift, escaping, closures

I would like to use the function for resting heart rate from HealthKit - defined in this thread:

[Query to Healthstore for Resting Heart Rate not returning any values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391037/query-to-healthstore-for-resting-heart-rate-not-returning-any-values)

```
func getuserRestingHeartRate(completion: @escaping (HKQuantitySample) -> Void) {

guard let restingHeartRateSampleType = HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .restingHeartRate) else {
    print("Resting Heart Rate Sample Type is no longer available in HealthKit")
    return
}

//1. Use HKQuery to load the most recent samples.
let mostRecentPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: Date.distantPast, 
                                                      end: Date(), 
                                                      options: .strictEndDate)
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: false)

//let limit = 1
let sampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: restingHeartRateSampleType,
                                            predicate: mostRecentPredicate,
                                            limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit,
                                            sortDescriptors:
[sortDescriptor]) { (query, samples, error) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let samples = samples,
            let mostRecentSample = samples.first as? HKQuantitySample else {
                print("getUserRestingHeartRate sample is missing")
                return
        }
        completion(mostRecentSample)
    }
}
HKHealthStore().execute(sampleQuery)
```

}

But I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax in Swift (5.X)! Above my skill level I guess...

Have tried this:

```
var restingHeartRate: HKQuantitySample?

getuserRestingHeartRate(completion: (HKQuantitySample) -> (Void))
```

The above gives this error:
`Cannot convert value of type '((HKQuantitySample) -> (Void)).Type' to expected argument type '(HKQuantitySample) -> Void’`

```
getuserRestingHeartRate(completion: (restingHeartRate) -> (Void))
```

The above gives this error: `Expected type before '->’`

```
getuserRestingHeartRate(completion: (restingHeartRate))
```

The above gives this error: `Cannot convert value of type 'HKQuantitySample?' to expected argument type '(HKQuantitySample) -> Void’`

Comment: Please format your code. Use the editing tools provided, and read the hints.

Comment: OK - did the edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var restingHeartRate: HKQuantitySample?

getuserRestingHeartRate() { (sample) in
  self.restingHeartRate = sample
}
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
var restingHeartRate: HKQuantitySample?

getuserRestingHeartRate(completion: { (sample) in
  self.restingHeartRate = sample
})
```

This is a good introduction to Swift closures: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html

Comment: WOW - thanks for the RAPID response! BOTH your suggestions work perfectly. For some reason or other I can't get my head around the syntax (still confuses me - but happy it works & I can proceed! :) )